# How to remove signature from newlfm?

Tags: newlfm

I am using the \newlfm package and I need stdletter format. I was wondering if there is a way that I can get rid of signature?

```
\documentclass[10pt,stdletter,dateno,sigleft]{newlfm} 
\usepackage{charter} 
\newlfmP{sigsize=50pt} 
\newlfmP{addrfromphone} 
\newlfmP{addrfromemail}
\newlfmP{Headlinewd=0pt,Footlinewd=0pt}
\PhrPhone{Phone} 
\PhrEmail{Email} 
\namefrom{Name} 
\addrfrom{address
\today\\[5pt] 
}
\phonefrom{phone}
\emailfrom{} 
\greetto{Dear Mrs,} 
\closeline{Sincerely yours,} 
\nameto{Mr. }
\addrto{address
}
\begin{document}
\begin{newlfm}
some text
\hspace{1cm}
 \begin{flushleft}
\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{flushright}

        \end{flushright}
    \end{center}
\end{flushleft}
 \end{flushleft}
\end{newlfm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To create a MWE, as @Werner pointed out, you could refer to [this question](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe).

Comment: So you're interested in getting rid of the "big space + Name" at the bottom of the `newlfm`?

Comment: Yes I wanted to get rid of "big space + Name".

Comment: @Michael: So the example code you provide represents what your output should resemble (apart from the contents within the `flushleft`/`center`/`flushright` environments)? My suggestion would be to recreate the output *without* using `newlfm`. Is that something you would use?

Comment: @Werner:Just I wanted to have a nice template for a letter. Do you mean to remove the package newlfm and write everything from the first?

Comment: @Michael: Yes, I mean writing things from scratch. Why? A document class is supposed to limit the scope of what can be done, while packages are meant to extend the limitations of the document class. If your intent is to change some of the fundamentals provided by the document class, then you should consider changing it. If all you're after is writing some letters, then there is no need to stick to something like `letter` or `newlfm`. It can just as easily be recreated in `article`.

Comment: @Werner Thanks for your comment. I will go ahead with your recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are merely interested in creating a set of letters, there is no need to use the `letter` or [`newlfm` document class](http://ctan.org/pkg/newlfm). You can recreate whatever you want using the default `article` class.

Here's a quick draft:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{charter,lipsum}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace*{4\baselineskip}

\hfill
\begin{tabular}{l@{}}
  Address \today \\[\bigskipamount]
  Phone: 123-456-7890 \\
  Email: who@cares.com
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{}l}
  Mr.\ Recipient \\
  Address recipient
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Dear Mrs.,

\bigskip

\lipsum[1-3]

\bigskip

Sincerely, Me

\end{document}
```